# How to efficiently extract rows arrow package

Tags: r, apache-arrow

Please advise. I have about 30 csv files, each 1-3 gigabytes. The files have the same columns, I open them as one large file through arrow. I need to quickly extract sub-samples of rows from the entire huge file (just by row indices).

Here is my code what I do to achieve this result

```
make_part_of_data <- function(){
  #This is a toy dataset, in reality there are 5000 columns and rows in the gigabytes
  # in each chunk of data.
  make_str <- function() paste0(sample(letters,10,replace = T),collapse = "")
  m <- matrix(sample(1:10,100000,replace = T),ncol = 20)
  cbind.data.frame(str=sapply(1:nrow(m),\(x) make_str()) , m)
}
# make_part_of_data()

# make folder and write data
pth <- "C:\\Users\\..........\\Desktop\\csv_data\\"
dir.create(pth)
pths <- paste0(pth, 1:30, ".csv")
lapply(pths, \(i) make_part_of_data() |> write.csv(i, row.names = F, quote = F))

# read data set from parts csv's 
library(arrow)
ar <- pth |> list.files(full.names = T)  |> open_dataset(format = "csv")

# get my_subset
some_idx <- sample(nrow(ar),1000)
my_subset <- as.data.frame(ar[some_idx,])
```

My question is can I do this more efficiently, perhaps a different data format or what to do with indexing or redistributing the files in a different way ?

***************UPD***************__

```
idx <- c(25939, 46332, 129989)
```

.
.

```
f1 <- function(idx)  as.data.frame(ar[idx,])
 f1(idx)


# A tibble: 3 x 21
  str          `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`   `7`   `8`   `9`  `10`  `11`  `12`  `13`  `14`
  <chr>      <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 mlyeofuldo     6     6     8     3     5     4    10     6     3     4     1    10     2     5
2 bansggekod     5     7     5     2     2     7     1     3     5     6     2     2    10     4
3 qzvxvoloag     1     3     7     7     7     1     1     4     4    10     8     2     8     4
# i 6 more variables: `15` <int>, `16` <int>, `17` <int>, `18` <int>, `19` <int>, `20` <int>

 -------------------------------------------------------

arr <- as_arrow_table(ar)
 
 library(dplyr)
 f2 <- function(idx){
     arr |>
     filter(row_number() %in% idx) |> 
     collect()
 }


 f2(idx)


Warning: Expression row_number() %in% idx not supported in Arrow; pulling data into R
# A tibble: 3 x 21
  str          `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`   `7`   `8`   `9`  `10`  `11`  `12`  `13`  `14`
  <chr>      <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 mlyeofuldo     6     6     8     3     5     4    10     6     3     4     1    10     2     5
2 bansggekod     5     7     5     2     2     7     1     3     5     6     2     2    10     4
3 qzvxvoloag     1     3     7     7     7     1     1     4     4    10     8     2     8     4
# i 6 more variables: `15` <int>, `16` <int>, `17` <int>, `18` <int>, `19` <int>, `20` <int>
Warning message:
In lapply(args, function(x) { : restarting interrupted promise evaluation

-------------------------------------------------------

f3 <- function(idx){
   library(duckdb)
     arr |> 
     to_duckdb() |> 
     filter(row_number() %in% idx) |>
     collect()
 }
 f3(idx)


# A tibble: 3 x 21
  str          `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`   `7`   `8`   `9`  `10`  `11`  `12`  `13`  `14`
  <chr>      <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 mlyeofuldo     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14
2 bansggekod     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14
3 qzvxvoloag     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14
# i 6 more variables: `15` <int>, `16` <int>, `17` <int>, `18` <int>, `19` <int>, `20` <int>
```

...

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f1(idx), f2(idx), f3(idx), times = 5)

Unit: milliseconds
    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 f1(idx) 197.4283 205.1695 214.5792 205.4398 214.1452 250.7131     5
 f2(idx) 519.4437 531.4304 587.6870 540.4603 639.2232 707.8776     5
 f3(idx) 617.7904 626.1685 726.5460 639.2448 786.3480 963.1783     5
```

**UPD2----------------**

*your `arr <- as_arrow_table(ar)` is unnecessary, use ar in your f2/f3 functions; the ar is already a lazy arrow object, don't double-tap that*

I don't agree, I get an error

```
ar |>
     filter(row_number() %in% idx) |> 
     collect()


Error: Filter expression not supported for Arrow Datasets: row_number() %in% idx
Call collect() first to pull data into R.
In addition: Warning message:
In lapply(args, function(x) { : restarting interrupted promise evaluation
```

---

```
 ar |>
    as_arrow_table() |> 
    filter(row_number() %in% idx) |> 
    collect()


Warning: Expression row_number() %in% idx not supported in Arrow; pulling data into R
# A tibble: 3 x 21
  str        `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`   `7`   `8`   `9`  `10`  `11`  `12`  `13`  `14`  `15`
  <chr>    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 zyizdsb~     8     5    10     2     4     8     6     5     1     5     7     9     6    10     9
2 taqqvry~    10     1     9     7     8     6     6     8     8     4     3     1     7     6     9
3 qbbolyr~     4     5     5     3     1     1     2     4     7     1     3     3     8     2     6
# i 5 more variables: `16` <int>, `17` <int>, `18` <int>, `19` <int>, `20` <int>
Warning message:
In lapply(args, function(x) { : restarting interrupted promise evaluation
```

---

*The `f3` should work fine*

But for some reason it doesn't work.
Compare the conclusions of the two tables, they are different.

```
 library(duckdb)
      ar |> 
     to_duckdb() |> 
      filter(row_number() %in% idx) |>
      collect()


# A tibble: 3 x 21
  str        `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`   `7`   `8`   `9`  `10`  `11`  `12`  `13`  `14`  `15`
  <chr>    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 zyizdsb~     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15
2 taqqvry~     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15
3 qbbolyr~     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15
```

Comment: Why loading data in R in the first place, this sounds terribly slow. Consider using AWK to extract rows.

Comment: Are you sure that you can't do the same with the arrow?

Comment: At least `my_subset <- as.data.frame(ar[some_idx,])` makes a copy, in R and then you still need to download in a csv. Instead you could use `shuf` to store row numbers then use sth like `awk 'NR==FNR {lines[$1]; next} FNR in lines' line_numbers.txt foo.csv > sampled_file.txt`.

Comment: Could you please share a reproducible example as an answer

Comment: Your `f2` is reading all data into memory, that's what `Warning: Expression row_number() %in% idx not supported in Arrow; pulling data into R` is telling you. So for _this_ sample data where you are comfortable pulling it all into R, it will be okay. Good luck trying that `f2`-like operation on your 1-3GB parquet files. The `f3` should work fine. BTW, your `arr <- as_arrow_table(ar)` is unnecessary, use `ar` in your `f2`/`f3` functions; the `ar` is already a lazy arrow object, don't double-tap that.

Comment: @ r2evans  see my update please

Answer (score 0):

`arrow` does not currently support group/window operations like `row_number()`, but if you add in `duckdb` into the lazy operations, you can fake it. (See https://arrow-user2022.netlify.app/data-wrangling.html for further discussion.)

Quick demo:

```r
library(arrow)
library(dplyr)
arr <- arrow::arrow_table(iris)
arr %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  filter(row_number() %in% c(1, 10)) %>%
  collect()
# Warning in lapply(args, function(x) { :
#   restarting interrupted promise evaluation
# Warning: Expression row_number() %in% c(1, 10) not supported in Arrow; pulling data into R
# # A tibble: 6 × 5
# # Groups:   Species [3]
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   
#          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>     
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa    
# 2          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa    
# 3          7           3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
# 4          5.2         2.7          3.9         1.4 versicolor
# 5          6.3         3.3          6           2.5 virginica 
# 6          7.2         3.6          6.1         2.5 virginica
```

That warning indicates the problem. If we bring in `duckdb`, though, we can keep it lazy (until `collect()` and also work by row indices.

```r
library(duckdb)
arr %>%
  to_duckdb() %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  filter(row_number() %in% c(1, 10)) %>%
  collect()
# # A tibble: 6 × 5
# # Groups:   Species [3]
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   
#          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>     
# 1          6.3         3.3          6           2.5 virginica 
# 2          7.2         3.6          6.1         2.5 virginica 
# 3          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa    
# 4          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa    
# 5          7           3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
# 6          5.2         2.7          3.9         1.4 versicolor
```

In your case, you may want to add `mutate(fn = add_filename())` before the `to_duckdb()` so that you can add arrow's notion of filename to the fray, then `group_by(fn)` for your per-file row indices slicing.

Comment: Your solution is slower than mine, and the {duckdb} example did not work correctly